# How to set a value in the cells of the next column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have table with hundred of text entries.

I want to tag those entries according to the original text.

Eg:

```
TEXT (A)         TAG (B)
Facebook       Social Media
Instagram      Social Media
Stackoverflow  Good Site
```

I am using the code below.

But this only copies the column A into column B !!

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A5');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var tag = sheet.getRange('B2:B5');

  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) 
  {
      if(String(data[i][1]).match(/facebook|instagram/gi))
      {
        data([i][1]='Social Media');
      }
      if(String(data[i][1]).match(/Stack/gi))
      {
        data([i][1]='Good Site');
      }

 }
  tag.setValues(data); 
}
```

The current result :

```
TEXT (A)        TAG (B)
Facebook       Facebook    
Instagram      Instagram       
Stackoverflow  Stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myfunction() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A5');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tag = sheet.getRange('B2:B5'); 
  var vA= tag.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(String(data[i][0]).match(/facebook|instagram/gi)) {
      vA([i][0]='Social Media');
    }
    if(String(data[i][0]).match(/Stack/gi)) {
      vA([i][0]='Good Site');
    }   
  }
  tag.setValues(vA); 
}
```

Comment: You were pretty close.

Comment: I want to optimize it without having to write all the matches terms...
I want to match a list (Named column) in another sheet where I input all possibilities.
@Cooper
[I created another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305487/how-to-set-values-in-new-column-with-validation-from-a-named-range) if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong indexes. The array that `getValues()` returns looks like this:

```
[ [ 'Facebook' ], [ 'Instagram' ], [ 'Stack Overflow' ], [ '' ] ]
```

So this code should work:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A5');
var data = range.getValues();
var tag = sheet.getRange('B2:B5');

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (String(data[i][0]).match(/facebook|instagram/gi)) {
        data[i][0] = 'Social Media';
    }
    if (String(data[i][0]).match(/Stack/gi)) {
        data[i][0] = 'Good Site';
    }

}

tag.setValues(data);
```

Comment: It is working for the strings I match.. but the others text data not matched are still copied.