# How to set values in new column with validation from a Named Range?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297344/how-to-set-a-value-in-the-cells-of-the-next-column)

I want to classify text entries by adding a tag in the next column.

I could do it using regex but it will take too much time writing all conditions like :

```
 if(String(data[i][0]).match(/acme|brooshire|dillons|target|heb|costco/gi))
      {
         labValues[i][0]='Supermarket';
    }
```

Instead I created a named list with all stores names (in another sheet).

If an entry matches a term in the list, the next column is set to "**Supermarket**".

I am using this script below... No bugs but nothing happens when executed !

```
 function tagStore() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A655')
 var store = range.getValues();
 var tag = sheet.getRange('B2:B655');
 var tagvalues= tag.getValues();
 var storeList= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("store_list");

  for (var i = 0; i<store.length; i++) 
  {
      if(String(store[i][0]).match(storeList))
      {
         tagvalues[i][0]='Supermarket';
      }
      }
  tag.setValues(tagvalues);  
}
```

Edit:

It is important to use a Regex as the "store" Values are not exactly the same as the "store_list".

```
Store Values : ["Acme Store", "HEB PLaza", "Dillons Group"...]

Store_List : [acme, heb, dillons...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to go with the regEx approach there is a more straightforward approach by retrieving the range as a list.

```
// For a Column
var storeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("store_list").getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});

// For a Row
var storeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("store_list").getValues()[0];
```

And then look if the values you are looking for are in this list with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Try this:

```
function tagStore() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A655')
  var store = range.getValues();
  var tag = sheet.getRange('B2:B655');
  var tagvalues= tag.getValues();
  var storeList= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("store_list").getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});//if it's a column
  //var storeList=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName("store_list").getValues()[0];//if it's a row
  for (var i=0;i<store.length; i++) {
    if(storeList.indexOf(store[i][0])!=-1) {
      tagvalues[i][0]='Supermarket';
    }
  }
  tag.setValues(tagvalues);  
}
```

Comment: This works if the values in store variable (A2:A655) are exactly the same than the Named List (store_list).
But the base values are more like "Acme Store", "HEB Plaza"...
Can I use regex with indexOf ?
 Thanks for your contribution again

Comment: I’d recommend putting all of those pertinent details into the question.